# How can I scale a ui web view differently on iPad than iPhone in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, uiwebview

The `UIWebview` takes up the entire screen on iPhone. I'd like the `UIWebview` to retain the same height to width dimensions on the iPad...but `Xcode` makes the `webview` adjust to the entire screen of the iPad. If I change the dimensions on the iPad storyboard, the `webview` no longer fits within the bounds of the different iPhone screens.

Comment: You can using sizeClass or Programmatically to set constraint.

Comment: Set constraints leading, trailing, bottom &Top.

Comment: If I use constraints on the storyboard viewing as iPad, Xcode changes it for all devices. How do I change just on the iPad?